# warning from ruby version file

Tags: ruby, rvm

I cloned a project and it had a `.ruby-version` file to specify ruby version of the project. content:

```
2.0.0
```

when I switched into the project dir for the first time it gave me warning:

> ruby-2.0.0-p645 is not installed. To install do: 'rvm install
>   ruby-2.0.0-p645'

However it's true that my system didn't have Ruby 2.0 but Ruby 2.2 instead. Does that warning makes sense? Is there a way I use duplicate functionality of (~>) gem dependency in ruby-version file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the warning, you are using [rvm](https://rvm.io/). As another answer says, [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) can also use a `.ruby-version` file, but switching to rbenv isn't neccesary, and won't really change anything.

I don't think [rvm's .ruby-version file](https://rvm.io/workflow/projects#project-file-ruby-version) supports a range of versions. It needs to specify a version name that could be passed to `rvm use`, and I don't think there's any way to say a range of versions there.

You can:

- Install ruby 2.0.0 with rvm: `rvm install 2.0.0`. When you switch into the project directory, rvm will automatically switch you to using ruby 2.0.0 like the .ruby-version file directs.
- Simply change your .ruby-version file to specify the version of ruby you want to use instead. Just edit it in a text editor, or run `rvm --ruby-version use 2.2.3` to have it write the .ruby-version file for you. Now when you switch into the project directory, rvm will automatically switch you to 2.2.3.
- Delete the `.ruby-version` file entirely. You aren't required to use it. Personally, I don't use them and don't find them helpful. The .ruby-version file is meant to force a particular version of ruby to be used in that project -- but most projects work with multiple versions of ruby, and this isn't really neccesary, and as you've seen can be a headache when it's out of date and is trying to force you to use an older version of ruby, when a newer one would probably work fine.

Comment: Edited to specify that you want to use the whole string, say, `2.2.3` in the .ruby-version file. If you just say `2.2` that always means `2.2.0` even if you have a later 2.2.x installed. You, annoyingly, need to specify the exact version.

Comment: The point of `ruby-version` file is to enforce Ruby version you are sure your app and gems work with. It also allows other developers to use `rbenv install` to get exactly the same version, which is crucial.

Answer (score 0):

.ruby_version is used for [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)

You should install **rbenv**

or create `.rvmrc` for **rvm**

Comment: [RVM can use `.ruby-version`](https://rvm.io/workflow/projects#project-file-ruby-version) as well as rbenv (and chruby).